# How to create a cast to oid type in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, casting, implicit-conversion

I need to define an implicit cast for decimal/numeric data type to oid type in order to use the = operator in the where part of a query without adding the :: notation.

After reading the docs here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createcast.html I've tried adding this cast but it works only for 0 to +2147483647 oids because int4 in PostgreSQL are signed and oid type is unsigned

`CREATE CAST (numeric AS oid) WITH FUNCTION int4(numeric) AS IMPLICIT;`

I know that oids are deprecated and not recommended and also in PostgreSQL 12 there has been a breaking change about them, but I really need this workaround for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define that cast using the type input and output functions:

```
CREATE CAST (numeric AS oid) WITH INOUT AS IMPLICIT;
```

That will handle errors correctly.

Be warned the adding implicit casts on system types may destabilize the type resolution system, so that you get errors about ambiguities. With `oid`, that is maybe not a big problem.

Also, `oid` is not deprecated in PostgreSQL v12. What has been removed is the use of `oid` as a hidden system column.